# How to concatenate a table resulting from a query into another temporary table on a procedure stored on mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I have a temporary query, e.g :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table4 AS (select * from table1)
```

and then, i have a another table resulting from a query, like:

```
select column from table2
```

what I would to do is to concatenated this column as a new column on the temparary table. Inner join would not work because they dont have a commom column
This would be like the concatenate() on python with axis=0.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what you want to do.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: OP wants to copy one whole column `column` from `table2` to `table4`. But these two table don't have any foreign key. OP wants to concatenate it one to one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to add the concatenate results of the second query as another column of your temporary table. Doesn't make much sense without more context as why would you want the same results on the new column on every row. But here goes my solution:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table4 AS
    (
        select
            *,
            (select group_concat(column) from table2 group by null) as concatcolumn
        from
            table1
    )
```

I have grouped by NULL on the group_concat so that it groups through all the rows. Inside this "nested" (is it even called nested when inside a column definition?) you can add where conditions which would make this question make somewhat more sense. Hope this solution helps. Cheers,

*****EDIT****

Based on OP's comments and supposing that both tables have rows that are aligned (matching rows have same row number but no matching key). This was more difficult than I expected as this is tagged as MySQL but this DBRM has no ranking function. Here is what I came up with that is untested.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table4 AS
    (
        select
            t1.*,
            t2.column
        from
            (
            select t.*,@rownum := @rownum + 1 as rank from table1 t, (select @rownum := 0) r
            ) t1
        join
            (
            select t.*,@rownum := @rownum + 1 as rank from table2 t, (select @rownum := 0) r
            ) t2
        on
            t1.rank = t2.rank
    )
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is what he meant.

Comment: @lucas862 Note that GROUP_CONCAT is limit to 1024 it's in the manual ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)   So you need to run the query `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len  = @@max_allowed_packet` first

Comment: the new column that I selected on the query (select column from table2) should be placed as a column on the temporary table created (table4).

Comment: this command places the whole column concatenated in every row, this not what i meant

Comment: @lucas862 it would help if you would provide what you mean in more detail. Do these tables have the same number of rows and are in the same order? In excel would this be the same exercise as copying a whole column from table2 to the right of table1 and the rows would line up? From your very vague wording of your problem and through elimination I will provide a solution based on this.